# Can't dotlock /root/sent

Tags: ubuntu, cron, mutt

I have a CRON script that emails daily using mutt.

This script has begun to fail, and I now get an email from cron stating:

```
Can't dotlock /root/sent.

Couldn't lock /root/sent

Could not send the message.
```

The wierd thing is that I get this *email* from cron fine, but mutt can't send email.
The cron job is run by root, so I don't think this is a permissions issue.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: cron reports are sent using `sendmail` by default, so unless you've changed that, it's still the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a /root/sent file/directory/link/other existent ? Is there an other process which take the lock for a while ?  Check with `lsof -n | grep /root/sent`. The rights are good on this file ?

Comment: There was a /root/sent.lock file, I deleted this file and it worked!

Comment: Sorry for necro but in my case i have no /root/sent, no /root/sent.lock, lsof reports no /root/sent* in use, and there are no other mutt processes active either ... I'm still getting this message. I'm stumped. Any other ideas?

Comment: What is your user ? Is it root or the home dir is bad defined ? Check if you can read and write to the /root dir. Check if the partition is read-only.